# Key Autopress in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, keyboard, 23.04

"+" is being autopressed.Help. I am using ubuntu 23.04 and 6.2.0-34-generic. Also please tell me how to disable laptop internal keyboard.I have tried disabling the two plus keys.

Could it be a driver issue?